# Split a string by format in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Assume we have a file with an arbitrary amount of entries. Each entry is structured according to the following format:

index,text,data

-Each entry is separated by a new line
-The text itself can contain commas

My question is, how can we separate the three tokens of the entry so that we can manipulate them separately?

Comment: A bit more information about the tokens: 
- the index starts from 0 and can reach up to any large integer number
- the data is an integer of a single digit (0-9)
- the text can contain multiple new lines \n

Comment: Check pythons [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: How do you want them separated? Like in separate files?